# Useful relationships that are true for every norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I am looking for useful identities that are true for every normed vector space $(V,||.||)$ on either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$(if your identity is restricted to either one of them, please say so).

I am looking for things like $|||f||-||g|||\le ||f-g||$ and so on.Therefore: Things, that are always true for a norm in every vector space. The best answer will be the identity that appears to be most useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this paper](http://www.emis.de/journals/BJMA/tex_v2_n2_a5.pdf) is what you are looking for. It contains strengthenings of triangle inequality and generalizations for multiple vectors.

Comment: thank you for this paper, but i think the equations in it, are more "innovative" than useful.

Answer (score 1):

The [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), valid for any vector space with an inner product and induced norm (rumoured in math competition circles to contain any symmetric, real inequality in several variables that has equality exactly when all entries are equal, if you're just clever enough in how to apply it):
$$
|\langle x, y\rangle | \leq ||x|| \cdot ||y||
$$

Comment: yes, you are right. csi is a strong one, but the inner product thing, makes it not-applicable in most of all general case that i am interested in. :-). Despite, you get a +1